# Python intersection of 2 UNICODE tuple/List

Tags: python, list, unicode, intersection

I am trying to search words from a file and appending resulting words from each line to a Tuple. And then I want to find intersecting words from the two tuples list_1 and list_2. But i get error-

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

import re

list_1 = []

list_2 = []

datafile = open(filename)

for line1 in datafile:

```
if '1st word to be searched' in line1:
    s = line1
    left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+1stWordToBeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
    set1 = {left, right}

    list_1.extend([left,right])
    list_1 = list(list_1)
```

datafile1 = open(filename)

for line2 in datafile1:

```
if ' 2nd word to be searched' in line2:
    s = line2
    left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+2ndWordTbeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
    set2 = {left, right}

    list_2.extend([left,right])
    list_2 = list(list_2)
```

result = set1.intersection(set2)

print (result)

in first for loop- The 'findall' searches for sentences with the word "number".
And then finds words to Left and Right of the word "number". And Creates a list-

*list_1 = [of, a, of, elements]*

in Second for loop- Findall searches for word "modern". and gives words to its Left and Right. And creates a 2nd list-

*list_2 = [of, all, elements, are]*

The File- Essays can consist of a **number** of elements, including literary criticism, political manifestos, learned arguments, observations of daily life, recollections, and reflections of the author of all **modern** elements are written in prose, but works in verse have been dubbed essays.

When list_1 and list_2 are obtained, the words common in them should be obtained.
**Please note the file is NOT a English file. It is in a different Language.**

Comment: Each of your lists contain *another* list. Did you mean to use `list.extend()` instead of `list.append()` instead, perhaps?

Comment: I tried using .extend() but it gives me empty set()

Answer (score 0):

You append one list object to each of your lists:

```
list_1.append([left,right])
```

and

```
list_2.append([left,right])
```

This gives you `[[left, right]]` for both lists, so you are trying to put the nested `[left, right]` list into a set as one element.

Normally, if you wanted to add multiple elements to an existing list, you'd use `list.extend()`:

```
list_1.extend([left, right])
```

However, since your lists were empty in the first place and all you wanted to do was create a set intersection, you could just produce *sets* from those two elements in one step:

```
left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+1stWordToBeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
set1 = {left, right}

left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+2ndWordToBeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
set2 = {left, right}

result = set1.intersection(set2)
```

Note that you are ignoring all but the first two words! You are using `[0]` to take the first result of the `findall()` list here.

If you wanted to create an intersection of all the words, you could use a set comprehension to extract all the words into a set:

```
set1 = {word for matched in re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+1stWordToBeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)
             for word in matched}

set1 = {word for matched in re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+2ndWordToBeSearched\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)
             for word in matched}

result = set1.intersection(set2)
```

Comment: To Martijn Pieters- I get empty set()

Comment: @Trish: then there is no intersection between the two sets, simple as that.

Comment: No there is! 4 of the words are similar, but i get no output.

Comment: @Trish: similar does not mean they are the same. Please update your question with a [mcve] if you want us to be able to help here; we cannot read your mind or your computer screen from where we are.

Comment: @Trish: that's not what I meant. Please provide a *working* example, with sample input and expected output, as well as the output you do get instead.

Comment: @Trish: Your code only ever looked at the *first* match, not all matches. Updated.

Comment: @Trish: this is not really a support desk or help line. I've answered your initial question (why you got the error message). I've even continued to help after you altered and expanded your question. If this still doesn't work for you probably have to ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

There you have list inside list. fix it.

```
result = set(list_1).intersection(list_2)
```

set([]) = Ok
set([[],[]]) = Failed because list can't be hashed

Comment: Then what do i do? I have used 'tuple'